# use webpack ant typescript to compile react ,failled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I use webpack typescript to compile react tsx fille but get some error

[image]

webpack base config like this

[image]

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to enable the `jsx`option in your `tsconfig.json`. Like this :

```
{
    compilerOptions: {
        //...options
        jsx: "react"
    }
}
```

To target a React compilation. It should work. Be sure that `React`is in scope.

Relevant [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Comment: i'm quite surprised at the way you included the awesome typescript loader. it does not seem correct. `source-map-loader` and ts loader are two different rules. If you have a reproducible project I will try and debug it.
From the docs : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html#create-a-webpack-configuration-file